# Change class of an HTML element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class

I need to change on the fly the class of an HTML element depending on the choice made by an user with a radio button but the problem is that I get the message

"Erreur : missing ) after argument list
Fichier Source : website
Ligne : 1, Colonne : 71
Code Source :
document.getElementById('jj_conjoint').setAttribute('class','validate['required']');".

my code :

```
<label>Husband/Wife :</label>
    <input type="radio" name="not_single" value="yes" onclick="document.getElementById('birthdate_partner').setAttribute('class','validate['required']');">yes
    <input type="radio" name="not_single" value="no" checked="checked">no


<select name="birthdate_partner" id="birthdate_partner">
   <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
   <option value="1987" >1987</option>
   <option value="1986" >1986</option>
   <option value="1985" >1985</option>
   <option value="1984" >1984</option>
</select>
```

Comment: As you can maybe see from the syntax highlighting, it is indeed wrong what you do: you have a string(`'validate['`), followed by a variable (`required`), followed by another string (`']'`).

Can we see the entire code somewhere? I think it could help understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(birthdate_partner)
```

is referring to a variable called `birthdate_partner`. Instead, you should pass the ID as a string:

```
document.getElementById('birthdate_partner')
```

The variable `birthdate_partner` is never assigned to some value, so it is `undefined`, resulting in this being called:

```
document.getElementById(undefined)
```

which does not work.

Comment: This can work, since `undefined` is just a variable the way you use it. Suppose you would say `var undefined = 'birthdate_partner'`, this would work just fine. It only works because you never defined `undefined`.

Comment: @Daan Wilmer: You're compeltely correct. However I assumed the OP did not set the `undefined` variable. It isn't a good practice anyway. To make really sure you have `undefined` you can always put this in a closure or define another variable with no value.

Answer (score 3):

You have not quoted the ID string, so `document.getElementById` returns a `null` because the unquoted string is seen as an uninitialised variable, which will evaluate to `undefined`.

```
document.getElementById('birthdate_partner').setAttribute('class',validate['required']);
```

Comment: This way (with the " ") doesn't work : I get "Erreur : syntax error
Fichier Source : website
Ligne : 1, Colonne : 24
Code Source :
document.getElementById("

Comment: @Bruno - sorry, I just changed 'em to single quotes.

Comment: Use single quotes inside the double quoted string.  `"document.getElementById('birthdate_partner')..."`.  You can't put double quotes inside a double quoted string unless you escape them.  But you can put single quotes inside a double quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to do this:

```
$("[name=birthdate_partner]").removeClass(className);
$("[name=birthdate_partner]").addClass(className);
```

Comment: Although this is easier I wouldn't advise using jQuery before knowing what's the difference between a string and a variable.